# Star rating not visible in white background

Tags: html, css

So I had used code from [this](http://www.dillerdesign.com/css/cookbook/component_star_rater.html) site to display star rating component on my webpage. Earlier it was working fine, but when I changed the webpage background to black (image), and the main container background to white, the star image disappers, I tried to fix it and found that setting opacity of container to anything less than 1, shows the star rating image, but on full opacity, the image disappers. Is there a way to fix the below star rating image css, so as to display properly without using opacity. Probably something to do with z indices maybe.

```
    /* 'star-rating' component */
    .starRate {position:relative; margin:20px; overflow:hidden; zoom:1;}
    .starRate ul {width:160px; margin:0; padding:0;}
    .starRate li {display:inline; list-style:none;}
    .starRate a, .starRate b {background:url(img/star_rate.gif) left top repeat-x;}
    .starRate a {float:right; margin:0 80px 0 -144px; width:80px; height:16px; background-position:left 16px; color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
    .starRate a:hover {background-position:left -32px;}
    .starRate b {position:absolute; z-index:-1; width:80px; height:16px; background-position:left -16px;}
    .starRate div b {left:0px; bottom:0px; background-position:left top;}
    .starRate a span {position:absolute; left:-300px;}
    .starRate a:hover span {left:90px; width:100%;}
```

This is my webpage css

```
    body{
        background: url('images/bg.jpg');       
    }
    .container {                
                    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    border-radius: 6px;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #ccc;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #ccc;
                    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px #ccc;
                    margin: 10px auto;
                    padding: 0 10px;
                    min-height: 660px;

                }
```

[EDIT} I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sayN9/). In the output window, if you hover below 'Currently rated 3 stars', you can see stars, but initally they are not visible

Comment: can you make a fiddle? also include your html.

Comment: edited question for fiddle link

Comment: What you need ? do you need to show the stars from starting?

Comment: yes, the stars should be visible, by default, which happens on setting opacity as pointed out by @zach's answers

Comment: You can use opacity:0.9 , its working fine.http://jsfiddle.net/sayN9/5/

Comment: actually I thought there might be some better way than setting opacity like this, which is kind of a fix to get things working, hence I put this question here on SO

Comment: It is also strange that if you remove the background color of your container css, the stars appears fine.

Comment: Check the updated answer below, its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your css code with below code.Its working fine, check the link below.

```
 /* 'star-rating' component */
.starRate {position:relative; margin:20px; overflow:hidden; zoom:1;z-index:100;}
.starRate ul {width:160px; margin:0; padding:0;}
.starRate li {display:inline; list-style:none;}
.starRate a, .starRate b {background:url("http://www.dillerdesign.com/css/cookbook/img/star_rate.gif") left top repeat-x;}
.starRate a {float:right; margin:0 80px 0 -144px; width:80px; height:16px; background-position:left 16px; color:#000; text-decoration:none;z-index:100;}
.starRate a:hover {background-position:left -32px;}
.starRate b {position:absolute; z-index:-1; width:80px; height:16px; background-position:left -16px;}
.starRate div b {left:0px; bottom:0px; background-position:left top;}
.starRate a span {position:absolute; left:-300px;}
.starRate a:hover span {left:90px; width:100%;}
```

[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sayN9/15/)

Comment: hey can you explain exactly what all you changed and why?

Answer (score 2):

Use `opacity:.999` or `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.999)` on the `.container`

This is because an opacity other than 1 creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), therefore sets the star image in respect to the container

> A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element which is either
>
> - the root element (HTML),
> - positioned (absolutely or relatively) with a z-index value other than
> - "auto", elements with an opacity value less than 1. (See the
> - specification for opacity), on mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+,
> - position: fixed always creates a new stacking context, even when
> - z-index is "auto"

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sayN9/1/)